# Graphics card utility that enables moving image(display) area of the screen to the right

Tags: drivers, display, graphics

Default resolution of my laptop's screen is 1366 x 768 if I change it to the 1280 x 768 Intel HD graphics utility let me choose to:

1. Center the image(I got black stripes of equal size on the both borders of the screen)
2. Stretch the image
3. Keep aspect ratio. Same result as in 1.

I look for graphics utlity which would let me to move the image(by image I mean displayable area of the screen, not wallpaper, WHOLE DISPLAY TO THE RIGHT) to the right.
The graphics card is Intel HD4000.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried display fusion? I **think** the free version can do this. I have the paid version which can do this for sure (and has other awesome features). Below shows a screenshot where I highlighted the tab and the section that would assist with this in red boxes.

[image]

Comment: I installed it and try to achieve it by this program and still no luck, I can't find this option.

Comment: I went through all tabs of this program.

Comment: @Yoda, I added a new screenshot to my answer to help show you where I am talking about. I know the title bar says "Steam", but that is only because it is licensed through Steam.

Comment: I checked it again. This moves wallpaper not displayable area of the monitor, but thank you for effort.

Comment: Thank stinks.... Sorry it didn't get you your goal... I have never actually toyed around with that setting, but thought it would work here. Perhaps someone else will have that special tool you need for this. Good luck! Worst case scenario, you would use Gimp (free version of Photoshop), to add the black bars on the sides of the pictures to create a picture that will resolve your problem (wide enough with black bars), but that is not an ideal solution.